# Python-can and Vector in docker

Tags: docker, can-bus, python-can

Background:
Today we have a application that is doing some stuff on a CAN network using a Vector VN1630A dongle.
It is working fine as it is on Windows, but the next step for us is to make it run as a Docker image, so we avoid cluttering the host computer with all different Python packages and versions.
So as a first step I'm trying to build a Hello world image where I just send out some frames, but I'm running into some problems:

```
Could not import vxlapi: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 53, in <module>
    canhandler = CANCommunication()
  File "./server.py", line 17, in __init__
    bus1 = can.interface.Bus(bustype=bus_type, channel=0, bitrate=250000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/can/interface.py", line 120, in __new__
    bus = cls(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/can/util.py", line 320, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/can/interfaces/vector/canlib.py", line 147, in __init__
    raise CanInterfaceNotImplementedError(
can.exceptions.CanInterfaceNotImplementedError: The Vector interface is only supported on Windows, but you are running "posix"
```

Code I'm using:

```
import can
import time

class CANCommunication:
    """
    main test class for bus and message
    """
    def __init__(self, bus_type='vector'):
        bus1 = can.interface.Bus(bustype=bus_type, channel=0, bitrate=250000)
        bus2 = can.interface.Bus(bustype=bus_type, channel=1, bitrate=250000)
        self.bus = {'ch1': bus1, 'ch2': bus2}
        self.last_message = None

    def send_msg(self,
                 id=0,
                 channel='ch1',
                 message=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]):
        self.last_message = message
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=id, data=self.last_message, is_extended_id=False)
        try:
            self.bus[channel].send(msg)
            print("Message sent on Channel {}".format(self.bus[channel]))
            print(f'Message payload: {message}')
        except can.CanError:
            print("Message NOT sent")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   
   canhandler = CANCommunication()
   while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        canhandler.send_msg(id=0x8ff)
```

requirements.txt:

```
python-can==4.0.0
```

dockerfile:

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8
# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code
# copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .
# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY src/ .
# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./server.py" ]
```

I have no clue on what the next step would be to solve this problem. Is it now possible to do like this with Vector dongles?

Comment: The error clearly states: _The Vector interface is only supported on Windows, but you are running "posix"_. You are running a Linux image in your docker container, but should use a Windows container

Comment: How do I change so I run a Windows container? Or does this maybe mean that I cannot use this dongle in this way?

Comment: c.f. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/windowsfaqs/#how-do-i-switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers
I don't know whether windows containers support USB passthrough